# KOHANA 3.3 + Vagrant - cache/logs directory writable, but not subdirectories

Tags: macos, kohana, vagrant

I had this working fine, and installed my setup from a git repo on a different box...and now, I'm getting the following error:

ErrorException [ 2 ]: mkdir(): Permission denied ~ SYSPATH/classes/Kohana/Log/File.php [ 69 ]

In my APPPATH.'logs', kohana created a 2014 subdirectory.  The 'logs' directory is 777, but the '2014' subdirectory is 755.

If I manually set the '2014' subdirectory to 777, then it will create a month directory '03', but also as 755.

This was working fine, and I cannot find any differences between the two.  What tells my Vagrant linux install (running under OSX) to not make the new subdirectories 777?

Comment: I should add, the same problem exists with my 'cache' and my 'media' directories...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I'll solve my own question here...

By running 'umask 0' right before 'vagrant up', the problem is resolved.

umask was previously set to 0022, which masked out the writeable bits of any directories/files created during the process started. By setting the umask to 0, it allows the vagrant process to create the directory/files (in the shared path) with the correct properties.